# how to draw multiple square using a loop to change the position only in java script?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, 2d, draw, ctx

I am trying to use a button that can build a small square every time I click it with changing only position x

this is the code but it doesn't draw a square instead it's drawing a long rectangle

```
let addBlock = document.getElementById('addBlock')
var c = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let s =0;
for(let i=0; i<=100; i=i+5 ){
addBlock.addEventListener('click', function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(10+i, 20,9, 100);
        ctx.fill()
         s=s+i;   })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rect(x,y,height,width)
```

I think you just need to change the width from 100 to 9.

```
ctx.rect(10+i, 20, 9, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the purpose of your application correctly then you want to change the position on each click. Your code doesnt work because the foorloop finishes before you even get to click once. My solution is the following:

```
let addBlock = document.getElementById('addBlock');
var c = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let i = 0;

let fn = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20 + i, 20, 100, 100);
  ctx.fill();
  i += 5;
  addBlock.addEventListener('click', fn);
};

addBlock.addEventListener('click', fn);
```

See my Stackblitz link for a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-4dhxpt?file=script.js

EDIT:

changed the code to run a maximum of 20 times:

```
let fn = function() {
  if (i >= 100) {
    return;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20 + i, 20, 100, 100);
  ctx.fill();
  i += 5;
  addBlock.addEventListener('click', fn);
};
```

Comment: I actually wanted to build a new square next to the old square every time not moving it ... but anyway I understand your code and change the idea to mine and it worked ... thank you.
but I need to use the loop to put a limit for the number of squares.... whenever I put the loop it stops working.. any idea what is the problem with the loop ?

Comment: i changed the code to have a limit i basically just added a if statement inside the function.